# Android change text view height after changing font

Tags: android

I have a custom text view inside a relative layout which is inside a scroll view.
My custom text view has a special font.
After running the program the height of text view which is set to wrap content does not change while the font is changed, so a part of my text does not show in the scroll view because the new font is bigger than the old.
What do I have to do to update the height of text view?

Comment: Please share your layout file.

Comment: did you call invalidate() for your textView after changing fonts?